# Flutter application spontaneously going to background

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter application that uploads an image. The problem I am facing is that on some android devices, and under some circumstances, the application goes to background. I cannot find out what are those circumstances unfortunately.
Here is the code for the screen if that helps

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<PostDetailBloc, PostDetailState>(
      listener: (context, state){
        if( state.uploadResult  == UploadResult.SUCCESS) {
          context.pop();
        } else if (state.uploadResult == UploadResult.NO_SPACE){
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
            ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
            ..showSnackBar(
              // consider offering buy
                SnackBar(content: Text('No space left in your account')));
        } else if (state.uploadResult == UploadResult.FAILURE){
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
            ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
            ..showSnackBar(
              // consider offering buy
                SnackBar(content: Text('Something went wrong, try '
                    'again')));
        }
      },
      child: BlocBuilder<PostDetailBloc, PostDetailState>(
        builder: (context, PostDetailState state) {
          return Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child:
            (progress != 0 || state.working) ?   ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('uploading ...'),
              onPressed: null,
            ) :
            valid ? ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Done'),
              onPressed: () async {
                await context.read<PostDetailBloc>().validateAndSave();
              },
            ) :
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('invalid'),
              onPressed:null
            )
          );
        }
      ),
    );
  }
```

I cannot even google this problem, as google gets confused and thinks that I want to send the application to background.

I understand that this might be too vague, and little to answer. What I am hoping is some pointers to where to look.

Is there a condition - like maybe lack of memory - that makes android send the app to background?

Comment: How do you know it's the app going to background, and not a crash?

Comment: because you can bring it back, and it is at the same state. So it is not a crash